# All programs terminating unexpectedly in a Windows 7 environment

Tags: windows-7, crash

Recently I have been facing some issues with my operating system, which is a 32-bit Windows 7. As far as I think these are memory issues.

When I boot my system, after some time, a message pops up, saying

> (i)some_program not responding, it needs to terminate.

When I click ok, another message pops up saying someother_program not responding. And it keeps on popping up, until all the OS services stops, and I had to restart my system. But when I restarted my system, it said no bootable devices found. But if I reboot my system after some time, it starts up without any error, but again the same messages pops up after some time.

INFO:
I recently left my machine on sleep for a long time, and forgot to turn off. Since then, this problem is causing program crashing and ultimately OS crash on my system.

These programs are random, I mean it is not caused because of any particular program, but every time some different program crashes causing this whole problem.

Comment: This does not match the symptoms you would get if it was a memory problem.

Comment: Then what it could be?

Comment: Failing disk drive? What are the smart vaules for your drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be bad memory or a failing hard drive. It could also be any component between these devices and your CPU.

Before starting, update your question with more information:

- Your system’s components, with exact make and model
- Your hard drive’s SMART data

  To get it, I recommend using [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/). Start it, select your drive, click “View Output” and copy the entire text from there and paste it into your question, like this:

  ```
  smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-w64-mingw32-win8(64)] (sf-5.43-1)
  Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

   === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
   Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint F1 DT
   Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD502IJ
   Serial Number:    xxx
   LU WWN Device Id: xxx
   Firmware Version: 1AA01109
   User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
   Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
   Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
   ATA Version is:   8
   ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 3b
   Local Time is:    Tue Mar 31 22:25:42 2015 WEDT
   SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
   SMART support is: Enabled
   ...
  ```

  You may remove the serial number and WWN device ID. Do not remove anything else!

Diagnosing the basics is fairly simple:

- Get yourself a copy of [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). Let it run for a night or however long it needs to complete at least one, ideally more, passes.
- Check what your hard drive’s manufacturer is. Check the website for a hard disk diagnosis tool. Run the extended test or whatever it’s called.

If, after these two steps, you already have some error messages, continue reading:

If you get an error in Memtest86+, check all memory modules in all combinations in all slots. A slot could be bad or other side-effects might cause the error. If you isolated a faulty module, replace it. Reinstall your operating system, because on-disk data could be bad after passing through your RAM.

If you get an error while checking your disk, backup your data ASAP. Actually, do it even if you don’t get any errors, because backups are great. Then, replace your hard drive. I recommend not taking an image of the operating system because the data may already be corrupted.